# Jenkins fails on empty grep result

Tags: jenkins, grep, jenkins-groovy

I need to filter a file in jenkins. Filtering works as long as the result is not empty. But if the resulting output is empty, the pipeline fails with `ERROR: script returned exit code 1 Finished: FAILURE`

Example:

```
#!groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {

        stage ('mystage') {

            steps {
                    script {

                        sh "echo '' > myfile"
                        sh "echo 'foo 0' >> myfile"
                        sh "echo 'foo 1' >> myfile"
                        
                        sh "grep foo myfile"
                        sh "grep ba myfile"
                    }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

output:

```
+ echo ''
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo 'foo 0'
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo 'foo 1'
[Pipeline] sh
+ grep foo myfile
foo 0
foo 1
[Pipeline] sh
+ grep ba myfile
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

routing the output to a file with `grep ba myfile > catchoutput` does not work.
How can I output the grep result, without the pipeline failing in this edge case?

Adding a dummy line like `sh "echo 'dummyline that won't match' >> myfile"` seems to work but is a hack. Is there a clean solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take return value in a variable:

```
def ret = sh(script: 'grep ba myfile', returnStdout: true)
```

More info : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script.
Note you can also add `returnStatus: true`, so that jenkins step does not fail even if there is failure in the command.

Comment: `def ret = sh(script: 'grep ba myfile', returnStdout: true, returnStatus: true)` works, thank you!